# Import external jar in generator module of Jetbrains MPS

Tags: mps

I want to develop a dsl for excel operations with Jetbrains MPS. I want to import Apache POI in the generator module.

I downloaded jar file of POI and tried to import it by `Adding Model Root` in `generator` like below, but it doesn't help.
[import jar in generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J8mg.png)

Then I tried to import POI in `main@generator` like below, but I found only part of Apache libraries are offered, not including POI.
[import library in main@generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5P4w.png)

Is it possible to import POI in MPS? If yes, how to properly import POI in MPS to accomplish some excel operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should covers your scenario - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD20171/Getting+the+dependencies+right#Gettingthedependenciesright-AddingexternalJavaclassesandjarstoaproject-runtimesolutions

Comment: Yes. Actually, the key to solve my problem is to add jars one by one. At first I tried to import all the jars by adding a directory and it didn't work properly.